# Continuous Deployment with Codeship doesn't recognize environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, continuous-deployment, codeship

Recently I started to use Codeship as CI/CD tool for a small website that I am maintaining. I set up my Codeship project to deploy via sftp as [described in their guide here](https://codeship.com/documentation/continuous-deployment/deployment-with-ftp-sftp-scp/#continuous-deployment-with-sftp).

The part where it fails is in the production script. I created a `deploy` folder and a `production.sh` script which contains the line:

```
put -rp "${HOME}/clone/build/*" /path/to/remote/dir
```

However when running the build I get the following error:

```
sftp> put -rp "${HOME}/clone/build/*" /path/to/remote/dir
stat ${HOME}/clone/build/*: No such file or directory
```

Echoing `$HOME` in a test script directly in Codeship gives me my home directory, so the environment variable works. However, at the moment the batch script is run, the environment variable is unrecognized.

How can I fix this? I'd rather not hardcode the path in my deployment script. It also doesn't seem possible that this happens because I suffixed `production.sh`, whereas in the docs they only have a `production` script?

Comment: Got the same issue - did you solve this?

Comment: Support is looking into this, they're coming back to me

Comment: I recommend you to use rsync for the production deployment.

Comment: Try to use absolute path (e.g /home/codeship/clone/build) instead of ${HOME} for the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no answer coming from the people from Codeship, I resulted to writing the absolute path to the `${HOME}` directory. I've been doing this for a time now with a few different projects and it all seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

replace ${HOME}/clone with ~/clone

this worked for me